# Declare a type from array

Tags: typescript

How can I say something like the following in typescript:

```
interface X{
    value:number
}
var bar:X[] = []; // Not an error 

// declare a type to be the same: 
interface Y extends Array<X>{
}
var foo:Y = []; // Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am convinced it is a bug in the current (0.9.0.1) version of the compiler : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1355

[Try it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20X%7B%0A%20%20%20%20value%3anumber%0A%7D%0Avar%20bar%3aX%5B%5D%20=%20%5B%5D;%20//%20Not%20an%20error%20%0A%0A//%20declare%20a%20type%20to%20be%20the%20same%3a%20%0Ainterface%20Y%20extends%20Array%3CX%3E%7B%0A%7D%0Avar%20foo%3aY%20=%20%5B%5D;%20//%20Error%0A)

Comment: Yeah it seems to be getting confused.  ```Cannot convert 'Y[]' to 'Y'``` doesn't at all describe what the code is doing.

Comment: Should mark this as answered, because the issue is fixed in the linked work item. Verified with my current version at 0.9.7